# Purpose of the bootstrap property in NgModule

Tags: angular

In angular 2+, I learn about NgModule which can be passed in with a configuration object. Inside this object, there is a "bootstrap" property, which typically point to a component, say AppComponent. I am wondering what is the use of having this "bootstrap" property?

When the index.html is loaded, the browser/angular engine detects the  custom tag, it can simply search the list of components defined in the "declarations" property of the root module whose selector is "app". Once found it, it knows that the component to bootstrap will be that component, say AppComponent.  Hence why do we still need to manually define this "bootstrap" property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, accidentally bump into the website at https://angular.io/guide/entry-components.  I learn about EntryComponent.

```
An entry component is any component that Angular loads imperatively, (which means you’re not referencing it in the template), by type. You specify an entry component by bootstrapping it in an NgModule, or including it in a routing definition.
```

To answer my own question, AppComponent is to be loaded (by the angular framework, i think) imperatively and not referencing it in the template (index.html is not considered template), that is why we need to add it to bootstrap property in order to declare it as entry component.

Comment: Why then do we need an `<app-root></app-root>` declaration in the `index.html`?

Comment: Good question.  I guess that we need <app-root> so that it know where to render this entry component in the index.html.